# Convert string time into DatetimeIndex and then resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

Two of the columns in my dataset are `hour` and `mins` as integers. [Here's a snippet of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcjWe.png).

I'm creating a timestamp through the following code:

```
TIME = pd.to_timedelta(df["hour"], unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(df["mins"], unit='m')

#df['TIME'] = TIME

df['TIME'] = TIME.astype(str)
```

I convert `TIME` to string format because I'm exporting the dataframe to MS Excel which doesn't support timedelta format.

Now I want timestamps for every minute.

For that, I want to fill the missing minutes and add zero to the `TOTAL_TRADE_RATE` against them, for which I first have to set the `TIME` column as index. I'm applying this:

```
df = df.set_index('TIME')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df.resample('60s').sum().reset_index()
```

but it's giving the following error:
`Unknown string format: 0 days 09:33:00.000000000`

Comment: you could add your 'TIME' column (dtype timedelta) to your 'TRADE_ENTRY_DATE' column (dtype datetime I assume) - that would give you a datetime column you could resample.

Comment: and how do i do that please?
PS: i'm totally new to pandas